Conjectural values of some determinants involving Legendre symbols (I)
$\newcommand\Legendre{\genfrac(){}{}}$Let $p$ be an odd prime, and let $\Legendre\cdot p$ be the Legendre symbol. In 2003, Robin Chapman evaluated the determinants
$$\det\left[\Legendre{i+j}p\right]_{0\le i,j\le (p-1)/2}
\ \text{and}\ \ \det\left[\Legendre{i+j}p\right]_{1\le i,j\le (p-1)/2}$$
(cf. his paper  Determinants of Legendre symbol matrices [Acta Arith. 115 (2004), 231–244]). He also conjectured the exact value of his evil determinant
$$\det\left[\Legendre{i-j}p\right]_{0\le i,j\le(p-1)/2},$$
and the conjecture was finally confirmed by Maxim Vsemirnov in his papers On the evaluation of R. Chapman's "evil determinant" [Linear Algebra Appl. 436 (2012), 4101–4106] and  On R. Chapman's "evil determinant": case $p\equiv1\pmod4$ [Acta Arith. 159 (2013), 331–344]. In 2003, Chapman also conjectured that for any prime $p>3$ with $p\equiv3\pmod4$ we have
$$\det\left[\Legendre{i-j}p\right]_{1\le i,j\le(p-3)/2}=1.$$
Note that
$$\det\left[x+\Legendre{i-j}p\right]_{1\le i,j\le(p-3)/2}-\det\left[\Legendre{i-j}p\right]_{1\le i,j\le(p-3)/2}=x\det B_p,$$
where
\begin{align}B_p&=\left[\Legendre{i-j}p-\Legendre{i-1}p-\Legendre{1-j}p\right]_{1<i,j\le(p-3)/2}\\&=\left[\Legendre{i-j}p-\Legendre i p+\Legendre j p\right]_{1\le i,j\le(p-5)/2}.\end{align}
If $p\equiv3\pmod4$, then $B_p$ is a skew-symmetric matrix of odd order and hence
$$\det\left[x+\Legendre{i-j}p\right]_{1\le i,j\le(p-3)/2}-\det\left[\Legendre{i-j}p\right]_{1\le i,j\le(p-3)/2}=x\det B_p=0.$$
For any prime $p\equiv1\pmod4$, we write
$$\varepsilon_p^{h(p)}=a_p+b_p\sqrt p\ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ \varepsilon_p^{(2-\Legendre 2 p)h(p)}=a_p'+b_p'\sqrt p$$
with $a_p,b_p,a_p',b_p'\in\mathbb Q$, where $\varepsilon_p$ and $h(p)$ are the fundamental unit and the class number of the real quadratic field $\mathbb Q(\sqrt p)$, respectively.
Motivated by the above work, I have formualted the following conjectures based on numerical computation.
Conjecture 1. For any prime $p\equiv1\pmod4$, we have
$$\det\left[x+\Legendre{i-j}p\right]_{1\le i,j\le (p-3)/2}=a_p'-2b_p'+\Legendre 2 p(2a_p'-pb_p')x, \tag{1}\label{470324_1}$$
$$\det\left[x+\Legendre{i-j}p\right]_{0\le i,j\le (p-3)/2}=\Legendre 2 p b_p'-a_p'x, \tag{2}\label{470324_2}$$
and $$\det\left[x+\Legendre{i-j}p\right]_{0\le i,j\le (p-1)/2}=\Legendre 2 p pb_p'x-a_p'. \tag{3}\label{470324_3}$$
Remark 1. In 2018 I conjectured that for any prime $p\equiv3\pmod4$ we have
$$\det\left[x+\Legendre{i-j}p\right]_{1\le i,j\le (p-1)/2}=x,
\ \ \text{i.e.,}\ \ \det\left[x+\Legendre{i-j}p\right]_{0\le i,j\le (p-3)/2}=x.$$
This is still open.
Conjecture 2. Let $p>3$ be a prime. Then
$$\det\left[x+\Legendre{i+j}p\right]_{1\le i,j\le(p-3)/2}
=\begin{cases}\Legendre 2 p 2^{(p-3)/2}(b_p-a_px)&\text{if }p\equiv1\pmod4,
\\2^{(p-3)/2}x&\text{if }p\equiv3\pmod4,\end{cases}\tag{4}\label{470324_4}$$
and
$$\begin{align}&\ \det\left[x+\Legendre{i+j}p\right]_{0\le i,j\le(p-3)/2}
\\=&\ \begin{cases}\Legendre 2 p 2^{(p-3)/2}(2b_p-a_p+x(pb_p-2a_p))&\text{if }p\equiv1\pmod4,
\\-2^{(p-3)/2}(2x+1)&\text{if }p\equiv3\pmod4.\end{cases}
\end{align}\tag{5}\label{470324_5}$$
QUESTION. Can one modify Vsemirnov's matrix decomposition method or use other tools to prove Conjectures 1 and 2?
Your comments are welcome!

TeX note: AMSMath provides a frighteningly general command \genfrac that takes 6 (!) arguments, whose full significance I find it impossible to remember without Googling (see p. 16 of the AMSMath user's guide).  However, it can all be subsumed in a nice macro: \newcommand\Legendre{\genfrac(){}{}} (first argument (, second argument ), empty third and fourth arguments, and fifth and sixth arguments the first and second arguments of \Legendre) makes a Legendre-symbol macro.  I edited accordingly.

Is it supposed to be that only $a_p'.b_p'$ (the product, I guess) is rational, or was that a typo for $a_p', b_p'$?
